# Multiple youtube video on page - event all ready?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

is there any chance how to get info when all the videos on the page are in a "ON READY" state? (I need know this information and after i will make some another JS event).

All examples on SO / Google search are with one video. I did not find anything in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like variable listener (in this case counter listener) using setters and getters. Then you can specify the number of videos on your page and increase the counter each time a video is loaded.

Each time the video is loaded the counter is increased and you can check if the counter is equal to the total number of videos. When the counter is equal to that number, then it means that all the videos have been loaded and you can perform whatever you want.

Function `videoHasBeenLoaded()` in the snippet below should be used as a callback to your `on ready state` video listener (here I am using `setTimout` to simulate that event).

```js
function videoHasBeenLoaded() {
  loaded.counter++;
  console.log(`video has been loaded (no. of loaded videos: ${loaded.counter})`);
}

const loaded = {
  _counter: 0,
  listener: function() {},
  set counter(val) {
    this._counter = val;
    this.listener(val);
  },
  get counter() {
    return this._counter;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }
}

loaded.registerListener(function(val) {
  const numberOfVideos = 3;
  if (loaded.counter === numberOfVideos) {
    alert(`all (${numberOfVideos}) videos have been loaded`);
    // you code goes here
  }
});

setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 1000);
setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 2000);
setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 3000);
```

---

ES5 version without getters and setters using global counter.

```js
var counter = 0;

function videoHasBeenLoaded() {
  counter++;
  console.log(`video has been loaded`);
  allVideosReadyCallback(counter);
}

function allVideosReadyCallback(counter) {
  var numberOfVideos = 3;
  if (counter === numberOfVideos) {
    alert(`all videos have been loaded`);
    // you code goes here
  }
}

setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 1000);
setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 2000);
setTimeout(videoHasBeenLoaded, 3000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast reply. I dont know ES6, so this code is very hard for me, is there any way how to rewrite to old way / ES5 (variables with var , etc?)

Comment: @Mr.RJ I have rewritten it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdcqohzm/) for ES5 version.

Comment: set counter(val)
get counter

which browsers support it? I need IE 8 >= unfortunatelly :(  (This keyword get/set i see at first time).

Comment: @Mr.RJ I have updated the answer, check the second code.